# Effect of enlarging a GUI by a factor of 2

Tags: fittslaw

Suppose a typical GUI is enlarged by a factor of two (all sizes, distances, images, buttons, etc.) what effect will such a change have on the speed of pointing interaction, assuming the interface worked properly before?

My thoughts: 
This seems to be an application of fitts law. And a normal reasoning says that 
Since the distance doubled and the size of the target also doubled so the speed 
will remain unchanged. I am not sure if that is correct.

Comment: I don't think so.  You'd have to double the mouse movement speed as well.

Answer (score 4):

Your analysis is correct. Fitts law is:

> Time to Move = a + b + Log2(2D/W)

Where *a* and *b* are empirically derived constants that don’t change when you enlarge things, *D* is the distance of movement and *W* is the size of the target in the direction of movement.

Only *D* and *W* change when you enlarge things. If you “zoom in” 2x then *D/W* is unchanged and the Time to Move is therefore unchanged. You multiplied both the numerator and denominator by 2 so that cancels out.

To be clear, this assumes you double the distances between things, and double *both* the width and height of each control. If you merely double the *area* of the each control, then *W* is only increased by the square root of 2, so Time to Move increases.

Fitts “law” has its limits. One obvious one is that if doubling the distance exceeds the range of the mouse or touchpad (i.e., the user has to double-swipe the touchpad now to reach a control), then Time to Move increases. Or, if the original display were a touchscreen with unsuitably tiny and closely spaced controls so users were making frequent fat-finger errors, then doubling everything would decrease correct response time.